# How to render Mustache partials in Sinatra while using ERB as the primary tempate engine

Tags: ruby, view, sinatra, template-engine, mustache

I have a sinatra app that is mostly using erb for templates, but I am adding some mustache partials for blocks of html that need to be rendered on both the server and client side. I have a "views" directory where I'm keeping all my templates, including the mustache templates I'm adding. For example, the structure looks something like this:

```
views/
    index.html.erb
    _wingding.html.erb
    _widget.html.mustache
```

Let's say I'm rendering index.html.erb using this endpoint:

```
get '/' do
    erb :index
end
```

And inside that template, I want to render both of the above partials [*UPDATE: it turns out this `partial` method is not built into sinatra, but is included via a gem (see my answer for details), but it still relies on the main sinatra rendering component, so the problem here still stands.*]. So index.html.erb contains:

```
<%= partial :wingding %>
<%= partial :widget %>
```

The erb partial (wingding) renders fine, but the mustache partial (widget) does not. It causes the application to throw an exception:

> Template engine not found: mustache

I have included the 'mustache' gem in the project. I tried `'require mustache/sinatra'` and `register Mustache::Sinatra`. Both of these statements worked, but didn't solve the problem above. Any idea how to tell sinatra about mustache so that it can render mustache partials?

I'm setting my views directory by including this configuration:

```
configure do
    set :views, File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'views')
end
```

Version numbers:

- sinatra 1.3.1
- mustache 0.99.4
- ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the gem listed in the solution in my other answer caches output, meaning you can't use it to include the same partial with different locals in the same request, which makes it worthless for my purposes. So here's another (admittedly hackish) solution that I've settled on. I created a helper that will just deliver the contents of a given view:

```
helpers do
    def template_contents(path)
        File.open("#{settings.views}/#{path}") { |f| f.read }
    end
end
```

Then, I just do a regular `Mustache#render`:

```
<%= Mustache.render(template_contents('_widget.html.mustache'), { ... }) %>
```

This works great for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. First, I must note something I didn't realize when I posted the question. `partial` is not actually built into sinatra. It is being included in my app as part of the [sinatra-more](https://github.com/nesquena/sinatra_more) gem (discontinued, most of it's functionality is now in a project called [padrino](https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework), but still using sinatra-more in this app). The partial method is included like this:

```
require 'sinatra_more/render_plugin'

module Sinatra
    register SinatraMore::RenderPlugin
end
```

Anyway, that just adds the `partial` method (along with some other rendering helpers) but this method falls back on the built-in sinatra rendering code, so this fact is independent of the actual issue at hand in this question -- that sinatra does not by default recognize the mustache template engine. Turns out someone created a super simple gem to make it work, [sinatra-mustache](https://github.com/jxson/sinatra-mustache). You simply include the gem and require the library:

```
require 'sinatra/mustache'
```

That's it -- it just works! No additional configuration necessary. If you're curious how it works, the source code is pretty simple. It's by no means a one-liner to register a new template engine with sinatra (even saying "register" is a misnomer -- you basically have to implement it), but it's still fairly simple.

*UPDATE: This gem caches the output for a given request/template, so you can't use it a second time with different locals. I could see cases where that's okay, but that makes it worthless for my use case.*